# Problem running sys.sp_cdc_enable_db to enable CDC on Sql Server from java

Tags: java, sql-server

When I try to execute the `sys.sp_cdc_enable_db` from java I get the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not update the metadata that indicates database source_cdc_db is enabled for Change Data Capture. The failure occurred when executing the command 'SetCDCTracked(Value = 1)'.
The error returned was 15517: 'Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "**cdc**" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.'. Use the action and error to determine the cause of the failure and resubmit the request.
```

I do have installed on my machine the Microsoft SQL Server Developer (64-bit),Version 16.0.1000.6.

Has anyone encountered this error? Any idea on the solution?

Most of the solution cases I've looked at have the problem of ...principal "**dbo**" does not exist... but in my case this is different, it is complaining about ...principal "**cdc**" does not exist...

This is for testing purposes and no real production db has been used. Normally I created a user and gave the db-owner database permission and sysadmin permission and had this same error. Then I tried the 'sa' user but the same error again.

I am stresing out that I have no problem executing

```
USE source_cdc_db;
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db;
GO
```

from Sql Server MM

Comment: Are you sure you're executing as `sa`?